# How can I save files directly to my local ftp drive?

Tags: hard-drive, wireless-router, ftp, android, nas

I have connected my 1TB External Hard Disk to my Huawei Router provided by my ISP, which doesn't have much functionality other than creating an ftp server which I can access locally. I need help regarding downloading files directly to this ftp server, so that I can download 4K HDR movies (from torrents, mostly) from my smartphone directly to my external hard disk, without downloading a copy to my phone or my PC first then transfer it there. If there is any such software or app which adds this functionality for Windows 10 PC or Android, please enlighten me. If there is also any other alternative which isn't as specific but reduces the hassle by bit, then please also share that as well.

Comment: It would be pretty weird for a router to support USB hard drive sharing over FTP *only*, and not SMB. If you can mount the drive via SMB (Windows-style file sharing), that would solve your problem. SMB was designed to be a remote filesystem sharing protocol, including support for random access within files, whereas FTP was focused on transferring whole files all at once in a single stream.

Comment: no, I have a Huawei HG8145V Router ONT provided by my ISP and I checked, it doesn't have any option to mount my drive using SMB, just FTP